# Troubles with reStructuredText (with Portable Python)

Tags: python, r, restructuredtext

I'm trying to run [rst2odt.py](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/odt.html) and [rst2wordml.py](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/sandbox/rst2wordml/readme.html) with [Matti Pastelli's example](http://mpastell.com/2010/03/25/create-odf-pdf-and-html-report-from-a-single-sweave-document/) on a Windows XP 32-bit computer. The R step works well, then I get the files ascii-example.rst, ascii-example.rst and ascii-example.pdf.

With Portable Python 2.7.3.1 I get the following errors:
[image: 2731]

With Portable Python 3.2.1.1 I get the following errors:
[image: 3211]

I am almost ignorant about the Python language hence I totally don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you run again the program with the `--traceback` option as hinted in the error messages? The traceback could reveal some more useful information.

Answer (score 2):

**Not really an answer, but a couple of observations to look at**

It's difficult to tell but two things stand out - the error you're receiving for the 2.7.x version is that `print` was a statement in the 2.x and was changed to a function in the 3.x. Hence, it doesn't accept parameters ergo the error.

In 2.x `file` and `open` were effectively the same thing, and in the 3.x series `file` was removed, which is another error.

As to your "image size not fully specified and PIL not installed" - you'll either need to look at the help for rst2ody to see if it can be specified, or install PIL (which is straightforward enough using `pip` or `easy_install`).

I'm afraid I don't have Portable Python, and although I could suggest some kludges, I'm hoping this at least gives you some pointers...

Comment: Maybe the `print` error could be fixed adding some `from __future__ import print_function` at the very beginning of the files that call print and using python2.7.x

Comment: @Bakuriu that's a possiblity - and possibly `__builtins__.file = open` somewhere in the 3.x version, but as I mentioned it all seems a bit kludgy and would either fix it (which AFAICT should just work anyway) and could lead to more errors...

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to suggest (I can't debug an environment I don't have) - it might be worth contacting the maintainers and including a link to this thread - maybe you'd have more luck there?

Comment: @JonClements After adding __builtins__.file = open at the beginning of the rst2wordml.py file I get a new error: "read() dit not return a bytes object". Yes I will try to contact the maintainers.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yup - best not to try and kludge it... good luck

Comment: @Bakuriu I have followed your suggestion with python27 but that does not change anything.